# drop,dropRight,take,takeRight vs substring?

Tags: string, scala

I am learning `Scala` from [Scala for the Impatient](http://www.horstmann.com/scala/index.html) and Chapter 01 exercise has a problem

> 10. What do the take, drop, takeRight, and dropRight string functions
>       do? What advantage or disadvantage do they have over using substring?

The only advantage I see that `drop`(and flavors) will not throw `IndexOutOfBoundsException`

For example:

```
scala> "Hello World!" dropRight 100
res26: String = ""

scala> "Hello World!" substring 100
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -88
  at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:1919)
  ... 33 elided
```

What else? Memory efficient?

Comment: Readability and error-prone-ness. `s.takeRight(4)` is a lot more readable than `s.substring(0 max (s.length - 4), s.length)`, and is the latter even correct?, it might be off-by-one or something, hard to be sure just eyeballing it.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The main benefit is that it allows you to treat a String as a sequential collection of characters, much like any other Seq or List instance.

In fact, these methods (and other important transformational functions like map, flatMap and filter) are *not* implemented in String itself (which is, in fact, simply the Java String class, not a native-Scala class), but in the StringOps class (which extends StringLike -> ... -> SeqLike), and an implicit conversion ensures that a String is converted into a StringOps whenever you need access to these methods.

This means you can pass a String to a list-manipulation function and the function will receive a StringOps instance, work on it like any other SeqLike entity without needing to know it is actually a String, and hand back the results of the manipulation, which StringOps is designed to present back to you as a String.

If you know an entity is a String in a given piece of code, feel free to use the String-specific methods, but the availability of this implicit conversion means that you can also take advantage of a String's "character sequence"-like nature to treat it like any other list in situations where that may be convenient.

Answer (score 5):

Seems that you are right. All these operations use `StringOps.slice` method, that delegates to `String.substring` method.

So, except for the overhead of wrapping string and performing bounds validation it's the same call to `substring`.